# Launch several jobs from a parent slurm job

Tags: slurm

I would like to launch a job, which launches 3 jobs to allow them to run simoultaneously. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -n 3
#SBATCH -c 1
#SBATCH -t 00:10:00

# Job 1:
srun -n 10 -c 1 -t 3:00:00 python program.py sample1.bam -output_dir1

# Job 2:
srun -n 10 -c 1 -t 3:00:00 python program.py sample2.bam -output_dir2

# Job 3:
srun -n 10 -c 1 -t 3:00:00 python program.py sample3.bam sample3normal.bam -output_dir3
```

The problem is that the whole script is running as a normal script, so it does not launch a job for each "srun" command. So, until the first command finishes, the next one is not going to start.

How can I get that, when I launch this job, it launches the three jobs, so they can run simultaneously?

Comment: I believe all you have to do is convert the srun into a sbatch call :). Another option is to separate the commands with &, which should make them run in parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to submit one job that itself **submits** three other jobs, then as @Maarten-vd-Sande notes, you can replace the `srun` calls with `sbatch` ones:

```
sbatch -n 10 -c 1 -t 3:00:00 --wrap "python program.py sample1.bam -output_dir1"
```

That will submit three jobs, that are independent one from another. The main job will terminate right away. But in that case it does not make sense to request `-n 3` for such a simple job.

If you want to submit a job that **starts three tasks**, you would do like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -n 30
#SBATCH -c 1
#SBATCH -t 03:10:00

# Job 1:
srun -n 10 -c 1 -t 3:00:00 python program.py sample1.bam -output_dir1 &

# Job 2:
srun -n 10 -c 1 -t 3:00:00 python program.py sample2.bam -output_dir2 &

# Job 3:
srun -n 10 -c 1 -t 3:00:00 python program.py sample3.bam sample3normal.bam -output_dir3 &

wait
```

But then it does not make sense to have a 10 minutes time limit in the submission script and a 3 hours time limit in the tasks. Also the total number of tasks (`n-`) requested by the `srun` must match the total number of tasks requested in the main submission script. Hence the adapted script above.